# How to prevent Ionic 3 LoadingController from stacking

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my app, I have areas that fire off asynchronous service calls. So, when a user performs some action that's blocking, I show a loadingController instance. In the mean time another asynchronous call could be started and again I present another loadingController - but this one overlaps the other one - not a problem if they are standard loaders but these have a transparent background.

In previous versions of ionic the controllers didn't overlap each other.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check my answer @pedrodg

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the example from ionic 3 documentation below you will notice that they assign loadingController to a var 'loading', then it is called to dismiss the loader later on (loading.dismiss()).

```
presentLoadingDefault() {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });

  loading.present();

  setTimeout(() => {
    loading.dismiss();
  }, 5000);
}
```

To prevent stacking behavior you could simple have a variable at your core component or provider level instead of within the execution context of the method presentLoadingDefault() and perform check if loader is already ON within your method.

Here is how I would use it in a "loadingProvider":

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingProvider {

    public loading = null;

    constructor (
        private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
    ) {
    }

    presentLoader() {
        // this below will prevent "stacking" as long as we treat this.loading as a single source of truth for any loader:
        if (this.loading) {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            this.loading = null;
        }
        // the rest is as usual
        this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Please wait...'
        });
        this.loading.present();
        setTimeout(() => {
            loading.dismiss();
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Segey, I like that approach. But, what if the loader you are dismissing when presenting a new one, would actually be running longer than the new one you have presented?

Comment: @pedrodg the duration in my example will not matter, even if the current active loader still has a duration running and we need to show new loader - we dismiss old one and start new one with this code. Sorry if i misunderstood you. Try it:)

Comment: I think maybe I haven't explained the issue entirely. The loaders that are being presented are not being timed out. They are only dismissed when their asynchronous operation completes. So there can be a scenario where the first loader will run longer than the second, or vice versa, or perhaps even the second loader could outrun the first but not the second.

Comment: Ugh;) I guess I understand this a little bit more, do you have a plunkr code to share?

Comment: I got around this by structuring my code such that I only have one loader and the calls are wrapped in a promise so that only once all calls are complete we hide the loader.